# CakePHP 1.2 to 1.3 - converting findAll

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm converting CakePHP 1.2 site to 1.3 and running in a few problems. Since Model::findAll has been removed in 1.3 how do I go about converting this piece of code?

`$pages = $this->Page->findAll("category like '{$page['Page']['category']}'",null,'sort_order');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be more like

```
$pages = $this->Page->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('category LIKE' => $page['Page']['category']), 
    'order'=>array(...), 
    'fields'=>array(...)
));
```

Comment: OK @SoHo vote for This comment, He just answered 3 minutes faster than me :)

Comment: i might add that you should try to always model-prefix your fields to avoid conflicts (now and later): 'Page.category LIKE'

Answer (score -1):

I think it goes something like this.

```
$pages = $this->Page->find('all', array('conditions' => array('category like ' => '{$page['Page']['category']})));
```